# Auto Accept system Alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

Can I set auto accept for system alerts.
likes. When we access current location/ phone contact system alert will show.

I know the Apple will reject with this. How can I achieve this. ?

Comment: What is the point of an alert view if you're going to make your user automatically accept it? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: my guess is that he's working on a kiosk app and if some system alert (e.g. "okay to turn on location services?") comes up, he wants to be able to blow past that without the person in front of the device seeing it.  And yes, pulling these shenanigans would not work with the app store.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, for good reason. System-level alerts are handled outside the scope of your app and cannot be directly interacted with.